# Error processing permissions.2: Value "background" in Firrefox while reading add-on manifest

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

While loading firefox extension from local, it is unable to parse, not sure what's the issue.

Reading manifest: Error processing permissions.2: Value "background" must either: must either [must either [be one of ["clipboardRead", "clipboardWrite", "geolocation", "idle", "notifications"], be one of ["bookmarks"], be one of ["find"], be one of ["history"], be one of ["menus.overrideContext"], be one of ["search"], be one of ["activeTab", "tabs", "tabHide"], be one of ["browserSettings"], be one of ["cookies"], be one of ["downloads", "downloads.open"], be one of ["topSites"], be one of ["webNavigation"], or be one of ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking"]], be one of ["alarms", "mozillaAddons", "storage", "unlimitedStorage"], be one of ["browsingData"], be one of ["devtools"], be one of ["identity"], be one of ["menus", "contextMenus"], be one of ["pkcs11"], be one of ["geckoProfiler"], be one of ["sessions"], be one of ["contextualIdentities"], be one of ["dns"], be one of ["management"], be one of ["privacy"], be one of ["proxy"], be one of ["nativeMessaging"], be one of ["telemetry"], be one of ["theme"], or match the pattern /^experiments(.\w+)+$/], or must either [be one of [""], must either [match the pattern /^(https?|wss?|file|ftp|*)://(*|*.[^*/]+|[^*/]+)/.*$/, or match the pattern /^file:///.*$/], or match the pattern /^resource://(*|*.[^*/]+|[^*/]+)/.*$|^about:/]

````
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Music Keys",
    "description": "Adds global shortcuts for play/pause, next, previous to music/videos in YouTube, gaana, SoundCloud, 8tracks.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "options_ui": {
        "page": "options.html"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "background",
        "https://www.youtube.com/",
        "https://gaana.com/",
        "https://soundcloud.com/",
        "https://8tracks.com/",
        "https://play.spotify.com/",
        "https://music.amazon.in/"
    ],

    "commands": {
        "play_previous": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Ctrl+Shift+8",
                "linux": "Ctrl+Shift+8",
                "mac": "Command+Shift+8"
            },
            "description": "Play previous"
        },

        "play_pause": {     
            "suggested_key": {
              "default": "Ctrl+Shift+9",
              "mac": "Command+Shift+9",
              "linux": "Ctrl+Shift+9"
            },
            "description": "Play/pause"
         },

        "play_next": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Ctrl+Shift+0",
                "linux": "Ctrl+Shift+0",
                "mac": "Command+Shift+0"
            },
            "description": "Play Next"
        },

        "_execute_browser_action": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "windows": "Alt+Y",
                "linux": "Alt+Y",
                "mac": "Alt+Y"
            },
            "description": "Play/pause"
        }

    },

    "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"]
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be saying that "background" is not a supported value. I suggest you try commenting it out.

```
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        /*"background",*/
        "https://www.youtube.com/",
        "https://gaana.com/",
        "https://soundcloud.com/",
        "https://8tracks.com/",
        "https://play.spotify.com/",
        "https://music.amazon.in/"
    ],
```

Comment: but I see backgroud as a valid value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#API_permissions

Comment: Yes, but if you scroll down to the compatibility section, it says that Firefox doesn't support it (and only Chrome supports it).

Comment: yes you are right. But is there any other way of achieving the functionality of background in firefox?

Comment: That seems quite unlikely, and I doubt Mozilla will ever implement it (or at least without requiring user opt-in). Here's the page that describes the permissions Chrome supports: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions